# Prove that $A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)\subseteq (A \cap B) \bigtriangleup C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that Prove that $A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)\subseteq (A \cap B) \bigtriangleup C$

I've uploaded a picture with a Venn's diagram which shows that $(2,4) \subseteq (2,4,6,7)$ which means it can be proved. I'm stucked one line before I can show that $A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)\subseteq (A \cap B) \bigtriangleup C$. Can you please help me on how to 'eliminate' $(x \in B) \bigtriangleup (x \in A)$ on the last line?

[image]

Edit: second try
[image]

Comment: An inclusion needs only an implication, not an equivalence. So omit the term, and the implication is still valid (if a and b and c hold, then certainly a and c, e.g.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For symmetric difference, we normally use $\bigtriangleup $.

\begin{align}
A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)&=A\cap ((B-C)\cup(C-B))
\\
&=(A\cap (B-C))\cup (A\cap (C-B))
\\
&=(A\cap (B\cap C^c))\cup (A\cap (C\cap B^c))
\end{align}
On the other hand
\begin{align}
(A\cap B)\bigtriangleup C&=((A\cap B)-C)\cup(C-(A\cap B))
\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap (A\cap B)^c)
\\
&=(A\cap (B\cap C^c))\cup (C\cap (A^c\cup B^c))
\\
&=(A\cap (B\cap C^c))\cup (C\cap A^c)\cup(C\cap B^c))
\end{align}
Since
$$
A\cap (C\cap B^c)\subset C\cap B^c\subset (C\cap A^c)\cup(C\cap B^c)
$$
There is 
$$
A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)\subset (A\cap B)\bigtriangleup C
$$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ in the LHS, means $x \in A$ and $x \in B \oplus C$. So two cases:

1. $x \in B, x \notin C$, then $x \in A \cap B$, still $x \notin C$, so $x \in (A \cap B) \oplus C$ (it's in exactly one of them).
2. $x \in C, x \notin B$. Then $x \notin A \cap B$, and $x \in C$, so $x$ in RHS again, as it's in exactly one of the sets. Done.